# How do I make my text moving animation on a canvas smoother (less jagged motion)?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

How do I make my text moving animation on a canvas smoother (less jaggered motion)?

The page runs exactly as I'd want it with the exception of the motion of the text being very jagged. How can I make it run smoother at this speed?

Code:

```
<style>
               #cvs {
                   position: absolute; 
                   top: 0px;
                   left: 0px;
               }
           </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var context;
            var text = "";
            var textDirection ="";

            $(function()
            {
                context = document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");            
                setInterval("animate()", 360);

                textDirection ="right";
                textXpos = 5;
                text = "This is my video..";    
            });  

            function animate() {            
                // Clear screen
                context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                context.globalAlpha = 1;
            //context.fillStyle = '#fff';
            //  context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);    

                var metrics = context.measureText(text);
                var textWidth = metrics.width;
                if (textDirection == "right") {
                    textXpos += 10;

                    if (textXpos > 500 - textWidth) {
                        textDirection = "left";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    textXpos -= 10;

                    if (textXpos < 10) {
                        textDirection = "right";
                    }                    
                }

                context.font = '20px _sans';
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                context.textBaseline = 'top';
                context.fillText  ( text, textXpos, 440);    
              }  
              </script>
          </head>
          <body> 
             <div id="page">
        <video id="video" autoplay loop>
          <source id='mp4'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
            type='video/mp4'>
          <source id='webm'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
            type='video/webm'>
          <source id='ogv'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
            type='video/ogg'>
          <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
        </video>
                <canvas id="cvs" width="500" height="500">
                   Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
                </canvas>
             </div>
          </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jBHCN/14/

Comment: yep, change the interval and the movrment and you get the same result, except it is less choppy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By decreasing the interval time for your animation function. You currently have it set to be called every 360ms, which is less than 3 frames per second. Set it somewhere between 20 and 40 for a smooth animation.

Comment: I want it at that speed. Is there no way of creating some sort of motion tween

Comment: A 3fps animation will either be extremely jagged, or only very minor movements can happen. To keep the same movement speed, but get it smooth, you need to decrease the interval and also decrease the amount that your text moves by. E.g. if you changed the interval to 30, then you would also want your text to only move by 0.8 each frame.

Comment: @user2186669: I don't think you quite understand canvas. The canvas will only change when you draw on it. If you only draw on it every 360ms, it won't change in-between that.